# VB.NET Using ListViewGroup in VirtualMode

Tags: listview, virtualmode

Is it possible to use groups in a ListView which is in VirtualMode?

Answer (score 1):

A standard .NET ListView cannot.

The underlying Windows control has an undocumented interface which allows ListViews to show groups in virtual mode (on Vista and later)

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net) -- an open source wrapper around a .NET ListView -- does the hard work of using that undocumented interface so its virtual lists can show groups. [See here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/whatsnew.html#groups-on-virtual-lists) for a description.